Flink List field serialization with Protobuf
I have a Foo class that is processed by Flink in a DataStream:
public class Foo {
    private int id;
    public List<Data> data;
    
    // Getter, setters, and constructor
    
    public static class Data {
        private String bar; 
        
        // Getter, setters, and constructor
    }
}


When I run my application, I see the following warning:
Field Foo#data will be processed as GenericType.
It implies that this list is processed by Kryo serialiser that is pretty slow. I want to avoid using Kryo serialiser for this list. I tried to resolve this issue by using Protobuf based on Flink's serialization guide.
Here’s what I added to my code:
env.getConfig().registerTypeWithKryoSerializer(Foo.Data.class, ProtobufSerializer.class);

I also included the corresponding Maven dependency for Protobuf. However, I am still seeing the same warning:
Field Foo#data will be processed as GenericType.
Expected Outcome:
I want Flink to properly serialize the Foo#data field without processing it as a GenericType, and avoid the warning.
